# How do you keep a single object from casting a shadow?

Tags: rendering, light

Is there a way to prevent *a single object* from casting shadows?
If I shut down "Cast Shadows" on the light source then all shadows will be lost. That is not what I want. I want to be able to prevent a single object from casting shadows.

A use case may be a laser. If I were to use a cylinder to model my laser, and that laser was positioned between a wall and a light source it will cast a shadow on the wall, but it should not cast a shadow.

Comment: I recommend breaking this kind of post into several different questions. You are free to place as many questions as you want, but we prefer if you keep each post to a narrow subject (this also helps other people searching for solutions)

Comment: There are some valid questions in there, but they should be submitted separately. The rest of this does not belong as a question on stack exchange, it's more suitable to a discussion forum like blenderartists.

Comment: Ok, which ones do you consider valid?

Comment: You just need to split up your questions, check other questions here that are voted up, if you want to discuss many topics at once and general workflow issues, use a forum.

Answer (score 20):

Objects not casting shadows? easy, un-tick the `shadow` box.

[image]
<sup>*In Cycles 2.79+, **Ray Visibility** was renamed to **Cycles Settings**.*</sup>

As for the lighting, Cycles simulates the physical behaviour of light with some reasonable accuracy. All techniques used in real photography can be applied to lighting setups in cycles, The video also discusses the composite of various render passes, I think you'll find they are all possible in Blender. Be specific about what you want to know and you will get accurate answers.

Comment: Thanks, one less thing to worry about. Ok, next thing. What about making a light cast only specular like in the video? Is that the Glossy option?

Comment: @00Ghz you can ask several questions here so feel free to ask, each post should have only **one** question to limit the scope.

Comment: In Blender 2.79, this is under `Material` >> `Shadow` >> `Cast`

Answer (score 12):

For 2.8 and for rendering I found selecting the shadow mode to None to be working. It's under material settings.

[image]

Comment: What's the context for this screen? I can't seem to find a "Settings" panel like that anywhere.

Comment: @Ajedi32 it's in the materials tab.

Comment: It is working for me, maybe it was a bug back then. Thanks!

Comment: This is how to do it in Eevee. The other solutions are for Cycles.

Answer (score 12):

In v2.83 I found the setting as follows:

Selecting the object and then, in the sidebar, going to Object Properties->Visibility->Ray Visibility->Shadow (check/uncheck).

Note: Changing the material properties did not remove the shadow cast by the object.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

## Cycles, Blender 2.79

Select the object, and in **Properties / Object / Cycles Settings**, disable **Shadow**.

[image: shadow settings]

Comment: How is this answer different from the [existing answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/774/30849), except for bold text and a larger screenshot?

Comment: @Leander "Ray Visibility" in the other answer looks like a section that doesn't exist in 2.79

Comment: The section was renamed, I edited the other answer. You can also suggest edits to other answers to improve them anytime.

Comment: The comment by Regular Joe made me think the answer might be something different because materials were mentioned. Thus decided to make new answer. I'd suggest updating screenshot or splitting your answer into two for different version/(ranges?) with # headers. cheers

Comment: Sounds legit, I'll add some images later.