# No shadow for a specific object for a specific light

Tags: rendering, light, shadows

There are many objects in the scene, and multiple lights too. Now, if I do not want a specific object's shadow for a specific light, what should be done?

Note that there are a few answers [like this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/773/how-do-you-keep-a-single-object-from-casting-a-shadow) explaining the way to disable all the shadows of an object (then the object casts no shadows at all for any light), but what I want to achieve is disabling shadow of that object only for a specific light.

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to create a separate render layer where you have a collection with the object ad a collection with all the lamp except the one (and a collection with the other scene object to make a mask).

Comment: Yes, masking is the only way to go. But maybe you should explain this more in detail because I guess for not so experienced users this isn't so obvious to create from one sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 view layers and two collections.

Then separate the lamps and objects for each collection.

[image]
[image]

In compositor you can combine them like this:

[image]

Comment: This won't work with "many objects" and "multiple lights".